# Which old black and white movie is the end of the "(Don't Fear) The Reaper" video based on? (Not "Death Takes a Holiday!")

Tags: story-identification, movie

Back before YouTube was well policed, someone uploaded a video for the song "(Don't Fear) The Reaper" which was a movie that goes exactly like the last verse – there's a woman dying on a couch, then Death comes and the curtains blow and then she looks over her shoulder and says "goodbye" and flies out the window with Death.

The movie is very old, an early "talkie" maybe 1930s, and the couch looks like it's in a New York highrise, the view out the window is over the city. She is cheerfully waving goodbye over her shoulder as they leave out the window. The video used the movie throughout the end of the song after the instrumental break, but I'm pretty sure that video is gone now.

Any idea what the movie was?

Comment: Sounds like Ingmar Bergman, maybe

Answer (score 8):

Might you be referring to the HIM cover of the song?  That video is a mix of several old B&W movies along with more recent color films that have been given the B&W treatment.

There is a scene very similar to what you are describing starting around 5:32 in the video.  It appears to be from a Gary Sinise film, though I am unsure which one.

The final scene in the video with Death leading a host of individuals across a field is from the Ingmar Bergman classic *The Seventh Seal* ,

Comment: If this is the one, then the Gary Sinise movie is the [1994 miniseries *The Stand*.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Stand_(1994_miniseries))

Comment: That's Molly. https://youtu.be/k1xc8jXes10?si=2kKHOPgVDtChICD-&t=21059

Comment: At least I nailed Bergman.  :-)

Comment: Thanks, but it wasn't the one I'm looking for – I've edited the question now for more clarity.